# Kogito bpmn 2.0, intermediate signal parallel execution

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, kogito

I have created a basic bpmn 2.0 flow to demonstrate. I have a subprocess that I only want it to run once, and it has an infinite flow inside, it never dies. I have attached an "intermediate signal" on it. This signal does not cancel the subprocess activity. But whenever I send request to this signal, I also have to put an "end" event on its way. Otherwise kogito gives error "There is no outgoing connection". I do not want to put an "end" event on this process because it disables the signal, since it makes the parent process' state "Completed". How can I avoid this behavior? I do not want to draw an arrow back to subprocess since It creates another subprocess (I only want to have one). Thanks in advance

[image: kogito process]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you want your main process to wait for a signal, then invoke a subprocess  and then resume the main flow when the subprocess is done, isnt it?.
If thats the case, then you just need to add an arrow from the subprocess to the end node and remove the arrow from the waiting node to the end.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my subprocess is not infinite. When making subprocess infinite and signal not cancelling it, state stays ACTIVE.